# Macbook Pro 13 mouse freezes after wake up

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, performance, sleep-wake

I have a Macbook Pro 13" bought in December which means it is the latest available version.
(MacBookPro8,1 , 2,4 Ghz Intel Core i5, 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB)
I have problems when waking up from stop: for a couple of seconds the trackpad is frozen, I can see the mouse pointer but it is irresponsive form mouse movement or multi touch gestures.
Everything in the mac is on,screen shows latest open programs and the writing cursor is blinking( thus excluding that for that couple of seconds the system is only showing a PNG of the latest screen before stop).
This issue is very annoying, the system is so reactive that it really seems a usability problem.

Did anyone experienced the same issue? Or maybe managed to solve it?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: This is a guess: do you have bluetooth turned on? Maybe it's possible that the computer is searching for a blutooth mouse and freezes the trackpad. I use a Mighty mouse and have never noticed this when I wake my MacBook Pro up but maybe its possible. Try turning bluetooth off if you have it on, see if that changes things.

Comment: I had bluetooth turned on but it doesn't seem to be the cause. I tried both with bluetooth on and off and it still freezes on wake.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was happening?
It happens to mine as well! Erika